# Question had its view count lowered by 1k!

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

[My question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/how-do-you-calculate-where-a-ball-should-go-when-it-bounces-off-the-bar) had 2k views this afternoon and 6 hours later it's at 1k. Any reasons why?

Comment: Around that time I was having major issues with the site in general (Add Comments button not working, "Show X more" not working). I blamed it on Firefox lameness but maybe something was wrong with the site backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a mistake checked in w/r/t the way view counts are calculated, so viewcounts were artificially high -- the bug was fixed and they were all reset to be correct.